# Java Spring Swagger different API documentations

Tags: spring, swagger-ui

I have a Spring application where I exposed two rest interfaces for usage.
One is internally for in-house developers the other one is for customers.

Swagger does generate a nice documentation reachable under */swagger-ui.html*.
Under this URL it shows the documentation for both internal and external users.

Here is my Code setup:

```
import org.springframework.boot.info.BuildProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import springfox.documentation.builders.RequestHandlerSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.spi.DocumentationType;
import springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.Docket;
import springfox.documentation.swagger2.annotations.EnableSwagger2;

@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class Swagger2UiConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean(name="restInternalSwaggerApi")
    public Docket internalApi(BuildProperties build) {
        final Docket docket = new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .groupName( "internal" )
            .select()
                .apis( RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.xyz.web.internal") )
            .build();
        return docket;
    }

    @Bean(name="restPublicSwaggerApi")
    public Docket publicApi(BuildProperties build) {
        final Docket docket = new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .groupName( "public" )
            .select()
                .apis( RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.xyz.web.public") )
            .build();
        return docket;
    }
}
```

Now, I want to separate these swagger-ui documentations. So that our internal developers access it like
*/documentation/private/swagger-ui.html* and
*/documentation/public/api-v1.html*

Both not seeing each other.
How to do that?

I found some hints here, but they really were not constructive for me:

[http://sp ingfox.github.io/springfox/docs/current/#q13](http://springfox.github.io/springfox/docs/current/#q13) and linked resources
[Customize endpoints of dockets with springfox Swagger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44285341/customize-endpoints-of-dockets-with-springfox-swagger/44289781)
[swagger multiple versions in path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51982295/swagger-multiple-versions-in-path)
https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/963
https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/1263#issuecomment-210839308

If someone would yield me to the proper documentation I would also be happy.
Let me know If the question is hard to understand and how to improve it.

for version infos on java's maven:

```
<groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
<artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
<version>2.8.0</version>

<groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
<artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
<version>2.8.0</version>
```

---

In other words:

I want the different APIs reached by the DropDown-Box to have called by different URLs:

[image]

I want this, so I can give a customer a different URL with a different API than to giving another URL to my developer colleagues.

Comment: Did you found a solution?

Comment: @Dirk Could you figure out how to implement it?

Answer (score 0):

1. Swagger-ui is a module (one of many jars that swagger ui as a solution consists of) that contains html's and css's, thus if you need one more page (in your case api-v1.html) you need to add one more html.
2. Here are the [sources for swagger-ui](https://github.com/springfox/springfox/releases) based on which I have created a modified springfox.js file (for 2.10.5 version) that allows for showing only **one** docket that have groupName==prefix of the page(e.g. if you have your docket .groupName("**external**") it will be shown on the page **external**-swagger-ui.html
3. So in order this to work you need to add 2 files total [files placement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HdvbQ.png)
   Please note that html file is also modified to use custom springfox.js `<script src="springfox.js"> </script>` instead of the one that goes with springfox-ui jar.(in my case it is resources root as you can see on screenshot)
4. Default swagger-ui.html has no interference with this solution.
5. [Working example](https://github.com/vadimmityanin/swagger-multiple-screens-demo)

Comment: Hi @vadimmityanin please lay out the significant portions of your code inline with the answer.

Comment: @vadimmityanin I saw 2 springfox.js files in your git repository. Why did you need 2 js files? I tried your code but it did not work for me. I can still see 2 dockets group visible in swagger-ui.html

Comment: @aliceangel if you start my project(java 8) hit http://localhost:8080/external-swagger-ui.html and you will be able to see only external docket bean content.

Comment: @rbrtl the most significant part is the springfox.js modification i've made. Each Docket content can be tied to its page (just copy external-swagger-ui.html and change "external" word in its name to the group of your docket).

`code`
//show only dockets that have corresponding prefix
...
`code`
this part from springfox-not-minified-source/springfox.js that regulates that behaviour, but it is NOT needed, it is just for reference, for application to work you need one in the META-INF/resources/springfox.js